# Согласование в часто употребляемых вопросительных предложениях

Tags: согласование

Как правильно: "Чего ты ждёшь?" или "Что ты ждёшь?", "Чего ты хочешь?" или "Что ты хочешь?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Чего* — подразумевает *вообще*.
*Что* — подразумевает *именно*/*конкретно*.

*Чего [вообще] ты хочешь?  || Звучит более культурно.

Что [именно] ты хочешь?* || Звучит более резко (*Что ты хочешь? Отстань.*).

Если есть варианты, то оттенок "*вообще*" не подходит (нужно "*именно*") и используется "*что*":
*Что ты хочешь: печенье или штоллен?

Что ты ждёшь: письмо или посылку?*

"*Чего ты ждёшь?*" может означать "*почему*", поэтому нужно добавить контекст.

Answer (score 2):

Выбор выражения зависит от степени конкретности ожидаемого или желаемого (с точки зрения задающего вопрос):

> Чего ты ждешь? (какого события, какого действия с чьей-то стороны?) 
>  Что ты ждёшь? (автобус
>   или троллейбус?) 
> Чего ты хочешь? (какого развития событий?) 
> Что
>   ты хочешь? (эту конфету или вон то пирожное?)